# The set $A := \{ k \in G \; | \; \mu_G(S) = \mu_G(S \cap k S) \}$ forms a closed subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, topological-groups

There is the following result:

> Let $G$ be a locally compact group with Haar measure $\mu_G$. Suppose $S \subset G$ is measurable with $0 < \mu_G (S) < \infty$. Then $A := \{ k \in G \; | \; \mu_G(S) = \mu_G(S \cap k S) \}$ forms a closed subgroup of $G$.

I do not see why it should hold that $\mu_G (S) = \mu_G( S \cap xy S)$ whenever $\mu_G (S) = \mu_G (S \cap x S)$ and $\mu_G (S) = \mu_G (S \cap y S)$ with $x, y \in G$, that is, why $A$ is closed under the group operation.

Any help or comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $S\setminus xyS\subset(S\setminus xS)\cup(xS\setminus xyS)$,
where
$$
A\setminus B=\{u\colon u\in A \text{ and } u\notin B\}.
$$
Hence
$$
\mu_G(S\setminus xyS)\le\mu_G(S\setminus xS)+\mu_G(xS\setminus xyS)
=\mu_G(S\setminus xS)+\mu_G(x(S\setminus yS))=0+0=0.
$$
Here
$$
\mu_G(x(S\setminus yS))=\mu_G(S\setminus yS)
$$
because of the invariance of the Haar measure.

Comment: Thanks. I can follow your reasoning entirely, but I do not see how to conclude the result from it. Could you please argue a bit more?

Comment: $\mu_G(S\cap xS)=\mu_G(S)$ if and only if $\mu_G(S\setminus xS)=0$, because $S=(S\cap xS)\sqcup(S\setminus xS)$.

Comment: Just to be sure: the inversion in $A$ follows from $$\mu_G (S \cap y^{-1} S) = \mu_G (y[S \cap y^{-1} S]) = \mu_G (y S \cap  S) = \mu_G (S),$$ doesn't it? The second equality follows here by the translation invariance of $\mu_G$.

Comment: Yes, this is the case.